Parsing large Excel file in MERN cause Heap out of stack error, should I convert it to Python?
I have a working MERN app that parses Excel file and insert it in the MongoDB. It uses Promises and bulk insert. However, it needs to read large files, when it read about less than 200,000 rows, it finished above 7 minutes. However, above 200,000 rows, it would crash while reading the file (Heap out of stock memory) without even inserting one in the database. Checking the utilization, it got to use 100% CPU and around 60% memory.
Here is my MERN function, it returns a text file with entries of rows not successfully inserted in the DB:
...
import fs from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';
import path from 'path';
import ExcelJS from 'exceljs';
...
const parseExcelFile = async (req, res) => {
  const { fileName } = req.params;
  const filePath = path.join(directoryPath, fileName);
  const discrepancies = []; // holder for errors in parsing row
  let totalUpsertedCount = 0;

  const upsertEntries = async (entries) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i += BATCH_SIZE) {
      const batch = entries.slice(i, i + BATCH_SIZE);
      const operations = await Promise.all(batch.map(async (entry) => {
        const existingRecord = await Respondent.findOne({ IDNumber: entry.IDNumber });

        if (existingRecord) {
          const fieldsToCheck = ['regionName', 'provinceName', 'municipalityName', 'municipalityId', 'barangayName'];
          let parentGroup = existingRecord.parentGroup;

          for (const field of fieldsToCheck) {
            if (existingRecord[field] !== entry[field]) {
              parentGroup = null;
              break;
            }
          }

          entry.parentGroup = parentGroup;
        }

        return {
          updateOne: {
            filter: { IDNumber: entry.IDNumber },
            update: { $set: entry },
            upsert: true
          }
        };
      }));

      try {
        const result = await Respondent.bulkWrite(operations);
        totalUpsertedCount += result.upsertedCount + result.modifiedCount;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error performing upsert:', error);
      }
    }
  };

  try {
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    await workbook.xlsx.read(stream);
    const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
    let validEntries = [];
    let rowPromises = [];

    worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: false }, (row, rowNumber) => {
      if (rowNumber !== 1) {
        const rowPromise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
          const rowValues = row.values;
          const entry = {
            regionName: rowValues[1],
            provinceName: rowValues[2],
            municipalityName: rowValues[3],
            barangayName: rowValues[4],
            purokName: rowValues[5] ? rowValues[5].trim() : '',
            IDNumber: rowValues[6],
           ...
          };

          try {
            const locationMatch = await Location.findOne({
              regionName: new RegExp('^' + entry.regionName + '$', 'i'),
              provinceName: new RegExp('^' + entry.provinceName + '$', 'i'),
              municipalityName: new RegExp('^' + entry.municipalityName + '$', 'i'),
              barangayName: new RegExp('^' + entry.barangayName + '$', 'i')
            });

            if (!locationMatch) {
              discrepancies.push({ 
                lineNumber: rowNumber,
                IDNumber: entry.IDNumber,
                regionName: entry.regionName,
                provinceName: entry.provinceName,
                municipalityName: entry.municipalityName,
                barangayName: entry.barangayName
              });
              resolve('Discrepancy');
            } else {
              entry.regionName = locationMatch.regionName;
              entry.provinceName = locationMatch.provinceName;
              entry.municipalityName = locationMatch.municipalityName;
              entry.municipalityId = locationMatch.municipalityId;
              entry.barangayName = locationMatch.barangayName;

              validEntries.push(entry);
              resolve('Valid Entry');
            }
          } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
          }
        });

        rowPromises.push(rowPromise);
      }
    });

    await Promise.all(rowPromises);
    await upsertEntries(validEntries);

    // Sort discrepancies by lineNumber
    discrepancies.sort((a, b) => a.lineNumber - b.lineNumber);

    // Create discrepancy file content
    const discrepanciesContent = discrepancies.map(d => `Line ${d.lineNumber}, Household Number: ${d.IDNumber}, Region: ${d.regionName}, Province: ${d.provinceName}, Municipality: ${d.municipalityName}, Barangay: ${d.barangayName}`).join('\n');
 ...
    
    res.status(200).send(discrepanciesContent);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Failed to parse Excel file",
      error: error.message
    });
  }
};

I tried Microsoft CoPilot to convert the function to a Python script. Somehow, it converted it but it ran for about 45 minutes on the same file of less than 200,00 rows. However, the resources it utilized is just small, 10% for CPU and 40% for memory.
Here is the Python script with redaction
import os
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateOne
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import sys
import time

def to_title_case(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return value.title()
    return value

def process_entries(entries, batch_size):
    operations = []
    for entry in entries:
        existing_record = db.respondents.find_one({"IDNumber": entry['IDNumber']})
        if existing_record:
            fields_to_check = ['regionName', 'provinceName', 'municipalityName', 'municipalityId', 'barangayName']
            parent_group = existing_record.get('parentGroup')
            for field in fields_to_check:
                if existing_record.get(field) != entry[field]:
                    parent_group = None
                    break
            entry['parentGroup'] = parent_group

        operations.append(UpdateOne(
            {'IDNumber': entry['IDNumber']},
            {'$set': entry},
            upsert=True
        ))
    
    if operations:
        result = db.respondents.bulk_write(operations)
        print(f"\rInserted {result.upserted_count} and updated {result.modified_count} documents")  # Status update
        return result.upserted_count + result.modified_count
    return 0

def parse_excel_file(file_path, batch_size):
    discrepancies = []
    total_upserted_count = 0

    # Check if the file exists
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        print(f"File not found: {file_path}")
        return

    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    valid_entries = []

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        sys.stdout.write(f"\rProcessing row {index + 2}")  # Status update
        sys.stdout.flush()
        entry = {
            'regionName': row.iloc[0],
            'provinceName': row.iloc[1],
            'municipalityName': row.iloc[2],
            'barangayName': row.iloc[3],
            'purokName': row.iloc[4].strip() if pd.notna(row.iloc[4]) else '',
            'ID': row.iloc[5],
            'firstname': to_title_case(row.iloc[6]),
            ...
        }

        location_match = db.locations.find_one({
            'regionName': {'$regex': f'^{entry["regionName"]}$', '$options': 'i'},
            'provinceName': {'$regex': f'^{entry["provinceName"]}$', '$options': 'i'},
            'municipalityName': {'$regex': f'^{entry["municipalityName"]}$', '$options': 'i'},
            'barangayName': {'$regex': f'^{entry["barangayName"]}$', '$options': 'i'}
        })

        if not location_match:
            discrepancies.append({
                'lineNumber': index + 2,
                'IDNumber': entry['IDNumber'],
                'regionName': entry['regionName'],
                'provinceName': entry['provinceName'],
                'municipalityName': entry['municipalityName'],
                'barangayName': entry['barangayName']
            })
        else:
            entry['regionName'] = location_match['regionName']
            entry['provinceName'] = location_match['provinceName']
            entry['municipalityName'] = location_match['municipalityName']
            entry['municipalityId'] = location_match['municipalityId']
            entry['barangayName'] = location_match['barangayName']
            valid_entries.append(entry)

    print(f"\nProcessed {len(valid_entries)} valid entries")  # Status update

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        future_to_entry = {executor.submit(process_entries, valid_entries[i:i + batch_size], batch_size): i for i in range(0, len(valid_entries), batch_size)}
        for future in future_to_entry:
            try:
                total_upserted_count += future.result()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing batch {future_to_entry[future]}: {e}")

    discrepancies.sort(key=lambda x: x['lineNumber'])

    with open(os.path.join(BENEFICIARIES_DIRECTORY, f'{file_name}_discrepancy.txt'), 'w') as f:
        for discrepancy in discrepancies:
            f.write(f"Line {discrepancy['lineNumber']}, ID Number: {discrepancy['IDNumber']}, Region: {discrepancy['regionName']}, Province: {discrepancy['provinceName']}, Municipality: {discrepancy['municipalityName']}, Barangay: {discrepancy['barangayName']}\n")

    print(f'Inserted {total_upserted_count} respondents. Check {file_name}_discrepancy.txt for rows with issues.')

def connect_to_mongo(env_file):
    load_dotenv(env_file)  # Load environment variables from the specified file

    mongodb_uri = os.getenv('MONGODB_URI')
    if not mongodb_uri:
        print("MONGODB_URI not found in the .env file")
        return False

    try:
        client = MongoClient(mongodb_uri)
        db_name = mongodb_uri.split('/')[-1]
        global db
        db = client[db_name]
        print(f"Connected to DB: {db_name}")  # Debug print
        # The 'server_info' method will throw an exception if the connection is not successful
        client.server_info()
        print("Successfully connected to MongoDB")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to connect to MongoDB: {e}")
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parse Excel file and upsert data to MongoDB')
    parser.add_argument('env_file', type=str, help='Path to the .env file')
    parser.add_argument('excel_file', type=str, help='Path to the Excel file to be parsed')
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', type=int, default=1000, help='Batch size for upsert operations')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    load_dotenv(args.env_file)
    ...
    file_name = os.path.basename(args.excel_file)
    file_path = os.path.join(BENEFICIARIES_DIRECTORY, file_name)
    print(f"Full path of the Excel file: {file_path}")  # Debug print
    start_time = time.time() # Start the timer

    if connect_to_mongo(args.env_file):
        parse_excel_file(file_path, args.batch_size)
        end_time = time.time() # End the timer
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
        hours, rem = divmod(elapsed_time, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
        print(f"\nProcessing completed in {int(hours)} hours, {int(minutes)} minutes, and {int(seconds)} seconds")
        print("Disconnected from MongoDB")


Can you look on my Javascript function and Python script to see if it can be improved. My issue with the original Javascript is the out of heap memory and can only process below 200,000 rows, while the Python script is too slow. Can Python use more resources so it can be faster?
Addendum:
The Excel file is already in the server. Since it is large, having to upload it will cause connection timeout. The Javascript function has an executable Javascript version which CoPilot used and convert it to Python script
